# Updating Key of Atom in ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

just started Clojure this week and am banging my head against a wall on something. While I understand that nothing is mutable in Clojure, I don't often don't understand how to update the value of an atom's key using the data it had previously been assigned.

2 simplified examples I'm struggling with are...

```
(def test-db (atom
{:name "jessie" :points 4}))

(swap! test-db update :points (:points + 5))


(def another-test-db (atom
{:name "roger" :nums [1 2 3]}))

(swap! another-test-db update :nums (apply str :nums))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have the value in hand, so you can use partial functions.

```
(swap! test-db update :points (partial + 5))
(swap! another-test-db update :nums (partial apply str))
```

Or more simply:

```
(swap! test-db update :points + 5)
(swap! another-test-db update :nums str)
```

Comment: You're welcome.  The best "thank you" on SO is accepting the answer. ;)

Comment: Haha sorry I didn't know that I could do that- thought that was for outsiders only! I got you.

Comment: In both these cases the word partial and it's enclosing ( ) can be removed and you get the same result perhaps in less time

Comment: Right you are @ArthurUlfeldt and @LeoGrapenthin!  Edited my answer. :)